# How to access All Apps menu easily

Tags: windows-8

I managed to access Windows 8 `All Apps` menu by right clicking on empty area of Start page and clicking `All Apps` icon on pop up bar displayed in bottom. Is there a another (easy/direct) way to access this All Apps menu (which I can't seem to find)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows 8.1, on the start screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

*Old answer, for Windows 8:*

<kbd>Win+Q</kbd> will take you directly to All Apps menu. And then optionally press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to remove the search field. If you're not in Desktop mode or the Start Screen, you may have to press the <kbd>Win</kbd> button once before, so you don't start searching in the current app.

Comment: Win+Q opens Search, which can be different depending on where you are. For example if you're in the music app it'll search for music, in the email one for emails, etc.

Comment: @Xandy yes, so you may have to press Win button once first, same as for your Win+Z

Comment: +1 This is the best answer on here IMO. If I am on the desktop, this immediately takes me to the All Apps Menu.

Comment: On Windows 8.1, this answer does not work.  I suggest that the Accepted answer be changed to the one by @TheComposer.

Comment: @SimonT yup, W8.1 changed how the search works. Before it used to show all installed applications when searching.

Answer (score 5):

For that, you need to switch to the desktop either with a click on the Desktop tile in the Metro interface, or a tap on the Windows-key.

Right-click the desktop and select New > Shortcut. Enter the following in the "type the location of the item" field that opens up automatically.

> %windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}

Click next, enter a name and then finish.

Comment: What does `2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0` do and how does this get you to the All Apps in the Start Screen?

Comment: @TomWijsman Microsoft employee https://twitter.com/Adman_NZ/status/241267716663676929

Comment: It's actually a CSLID located at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` that points to all apps

Comment: I prefer (my) keyboard way as a "Power user", but this is great to know as well. Will come in handy when configuring others' computers.

Answer (score 4):

Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Other than that I don't think there's a faster way. I mean you could press <kbd>Win</kbd> to get to the Start screen, then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to show the App bar and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show all the applications, which may be faster through the keyboard only.

Via keyboard shortcuts you may get to search for an application pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> and then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click in a blank space to hide the search part.

Answer (score 1):

Press a key to start searching for something and then remove that search term by pressing backtrace, so <kbd>Any key</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> might give you the full application list.